# How to get indexPath by tap on view in collectionCell with RxSwift?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a collectionView with cells. Every cell has a component imageView, I can tap on it and another controller will push.
I need to know exactly when l tap on imageView, what indexPath of cell is.

When l just tap on cell, not on imageView, l have this indexPath with the help of `collectionView.rx.itemSelected`, and l need to do the same but when tap on imageView in collection cell.

Help, please, maybe you have some good ideas :)

Comment: Can you show screen shots & code?

Comment: If a cell needs to know it's index path, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Desdenova no, probably not exactly the cell - the concept is when l tap to cell, another controller push, and when l go back to the previous screen, l don't want to reload my collection, l want to keep it in the same place, that's why l scroll to the last selected indexPath. And now l need to do the same, but with tap on imageView in collection cell, and it is difficult to understand how to do it right

Comment: Ok. You may need to find out why your collection view reloads. Because it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

By default, UIImageView ignores taps. If you are using storyboard or xib to create the cell, then you need to make sure the "User Interaction Enabled" checkbox is checked. If you are making the image view programmatically, then add: `myImageVIew.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

PS: this has nothing to do with RxSwift. You would have the same problem if you weren't using it.

Comment: No, probably we don't understand each other - let me try to tell you more details.

I have a collection with cells, that have background image and imageView. With Rx-bindings l can tap on imageView and another screen will open. It works fine.

But when l scroll collection, tap on cell (not in imageView), new screen open, l go back to the previous screen and collection stay in the same place - l did it with the help of collectionView.rx.itemSelected and relays. And now l want to do exactly the same, but by tap on imageView, and don't know how

Comment: My logic is: property collectionView.rx.itemSelected in cell bind to PublishRelay<IndexPath?> in cellViewModel. also create another relay and bind it with method scrollToItem(value: my indexPath)
When go to viewModel of controller, make bindings here and finally in viewController ask viewModel to scrollToItem, if index path is not nil. And l need to do the same, but with imageView tap